# How to add Custom Annotation in Mapbox during Turn-by-Turn navigation

Tags: swift, annotations, mapbox

I am using

*MapboxNavigation -> v2.0.0-beta.13*

I would like to know how to add custom markers in **Turn-by-Turn navigation mode View**

My goal is to add custom POI's during navigation and try to interact with them, e.g. tapping on them and maybe showing also further info on a callout view.

**THIS IS THE PREVIEW (NavigationMapView instance)**
[image]

**THIS IS DURING THE NAVIGATION**
I need to add N POI's in this view.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: as per example you need only need info of place?

Comment: No, I ll update my question with screenshots to explain better.

Comment: There may be many ways to achieve that, can you provide the code you have

Answer (score 0):

```
    import Foundation
    import UIKit
    import MapboxCoreNavigation
    import MapboxNavigation
    import MapboxDirections

    
    class CustomDestinationMarkerController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let origin = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.77440680146262, -122.43539772352648)
        let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.76556957793795, -122.42409811526268)
        let routeOptions = NavigationRouteOptions(coordinates: [origin, destination])
        
        Directions.shared.calculate(routeOptions) { [weak self] (session, result) in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            case .success(let response):
                guard let route = response.routes?.first, let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                
                // For demonstration purposes, simulate locations if the Simulate Navigation option is on.
                let navigationService = MapboxNavigationService(route: route, routeIndex: 0, routeOptions: routeOptions, simulating: simulationIsEnabled ? .always : .onPoorGPS)
                let navigationOptions = NavigationOptions(navigationService: navigationService)
                let navigationViewController = NavigationViewController(for: route, routeIndex: 0, routeOptions: routeOptions, navigationOptions: navigationOptions)
                navigationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                navigationViewController.mapView?.delegate = strongSelf
                navigationViewController.routeLineTracksTraversal = true
                
                strongSelf.present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    }


extension CustomDestinationMarkerController: MGLMapViewDelegate {

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: "marker")
    
    if annotationImage == nil {
        // Leaning Tower of Pisa by Stefan Spieler from the Noun Project.
        var image = UIImage(named: "marker")!
        
        // The anchor point of an annotation is currently always the center. To
        // shift the anchor point to the bottom of the annotation, the image
        // asset includes transparent bottom padding equal to the original image
        // height.
        //
        // To make this padding non-interactive, we create another image object
        // with a custom alignment rect that excludes the padding.
        image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: image.size.height / 2, right: 0))
        
        // Initialize the ‘pisa’ annotation image with the UIImage we just loaded.
        annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: "marker")
    }
    
    return annotationImage
}
}
```

Refrences:
Visit https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/examples/custom-destination-marker/
Visit https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/add-markers/

Comment: Thanks for your support but:

1) I cannot use MGLMapViewDelegate in the version I mentioned
2) Your example is only useful to customize destination marker